# Private publish of a google-add on not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

To perform a Private Publishing of Google-Sheet Addon in GSuite/Chrome Web Store for QA team.

**Steps Executed**:

1. Created a project in script.google.com and using clasp, pushed the latest code for google-sheet addon into it.
2. The prepared the manifest.json per Google’s requirement (attached for reference)
3. Then selected “Deploy as add-on” from publish.
4. Beforehand, prepared the zip, logo and screenshot per Google’s requirement.
5. Then on “Deploy as add-on” screen, selected “Add-on Type” as “Sheets” in addition to filling other fields as required.
6. Then went to Chrome Web Store>Dashboard page to upload the zip, image, screenshot, provided description, selected category, etc. and finally selected “Visibility options” as “Private”.
7. At the end, I published the changes.

Are these steps correct or have I missed something?

How to get this add-on visible in google-sheets opened by the tester that is added in “testers accounts”? Per Google, I have to share the complete link of the add-on with the tester. Then What is the point of adding the testers into “Testers accounts”.

Also, it is appearing as “Extension” in “Chrome Web Store”. Is it correct?

Comment: You must *NOT* prepare a manifest.json file.  That is automatically created by the Apps Script code editor.  I'm guessing that the reason it's showing up as an “Extension” is that you prepared a manifest.json file.  I would start over again with a different project file and try publishing again.  Once that manifest.json file has been uploaded, it may corrupt the whole process, and you may not be able to recover from that.

Comment: @Alan Wells: The default manifest.json file (that is created within the project as "appscript.json") is missing 2 parameters by default: name and version. Also, when I was trying to upload the project without the file named "manifest.json", it was constantly giving error. Hence, I was forced to create a file with the name "manifest.json" with required parameters to have a valid manifest file per google. Please suggest, if I am missing something.

Comment: Publishing to a test group will be going away.  The Chrome Web Store Migration
support team has stated that there are no plans to implement Trusted Testers functionality in the G Suite Marketplace.  So, that's the first thing you need to know.

Comment: @Alan Wells: Thank you, Alan for sharing the information. Will definitely take it into the consideration to proceed further. In that case, "Private" publish will be retained or not?

Comment: In the "Configuration" section of the Google Cloud Platform for the G Suite Marketplace SDK, at the bottom, there are two radio buttons for "Visibility"; one for "Public" and one for "My Domain (Only available to users at example.com)"  From the code editor, choose "Resources" and "Cloud platform project"  Then click the blue link.  Open the Nav menu.  APIs and Services - Dashboard.  Click the G Suite Marketplace SDK link in the table at the bottom.  Click the configuration (wrench).  If you don't see the configuration menu choice, refresh the page.  Scroll to bottom.